# Merge/convert textview with/to image drawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a text that is dynamic i.e. is a value coming from a network response.
I have an image drawable displayed at a specific position in a custom view.
I can not modify the custom view to change the layout for some reasons.
Is there a way to convert the text to some kind of bitmap and merge it with the image drawable?
Hint, I can pass a drawable to the custom view, so I control what is passed as image drawable.
But how could I convert the textview to I guess some bitmap (?) and place it on top of the other image?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a custom view is just to add to the onDraw function and draw the text via `canvas.drawText()`.

Comment: May be I misunderstood what you said but I can't touch the custom view. I can only pass a drawable. So are you suggesting to create another custom view?

Comment: Also I would like to keep the textview's background so it is not only just text (if possible)

Comment: If its a custom view, you should have access to it.

Comment: Access to do what? I already mentioned I can not change that code

Comment: If its a custom view, you should have access to the code.  But failing that, you can always plop a TextView on top of it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what is "plop a TextView". My problem is: 1) I have a TextView that has a background of certain color and a dynamic text 2) I need to convert this to a drawable.

Comment: No, you absolutely do NOT need to convert it to a drawable.  You can put views on top of each other.  If you don't understand that, I suggest you study android's layout system.

Comment: I see that my post is not clear. My question is not about layout. Is about library object that has a method that accepts a `Drawable` and I am trying to figure out from that if there is a way to do what I describe.